# Modx Evo: Unable to add new users since upgrading to 1.0.9

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have just upgraded a site from 1.0.6 to 1.0.9 and now am unable to add new users. I go through the process in the back end and all seems ok but they do not appear in the user list under Manager Users.

However, checking in the database they do appear in the modx_manager_users table, but not in the modx_active_users table.

Would anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a commone issue with 1.0.9 and is able to be fixed by installing 1.0.10

http://forums.modx.com/thread/83325/modx-1-0-10-rc-need-testers